# Flattening python pandas dataframe to a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an input as follows (tried to get the formatting right)

```
**key**   **value**

   'A'         63

   'B'        87.2

   'D'        1.4

   'E'       15.6
```

I need to convert this to [['A', 63],['B',87.2],['D',1.4],['E',15.6]] so that this can be stored in a cell, in an aggregation dataframe

I tried the following

```
   element_flatten=[]
     for ele in inputdataframe.itertuple(index=False):
     element_flattened=element_flattened +[ele]code here
```

I get something like [Pandas(key='A', value=63), Pandas(key='B', value=87.2)] - while what I would like is just [[A,63],['B',87.2]] etc

Comment: It would be easier if you had provided a [mcve] so that we know what `inputdataframe` is instead of having to guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `values`:

```
print(inputdataframe.values.tolist())
```

Output:

```
[['A', 63], ['B', 87.2], ['D', 1.4], ['E', 15.6]]
```